# React Context : Calling action inside Navigator doesnt re render component rendered inside navigator so state is not updated. why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-context

Using context, I am calling action (where I fetch data) from within my navigation. I want to use state (produced by reducer) inside a component 'Notification'. It seems that only if I call that action inside my component that state changes are shown in component. If I call from within navigator, component is not being re rendered so state changes that happen successfully are not updated (I do connect of course the component to context). What am I doing wrong?

**NotificationContext.js**

```
const notificationsReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'fetch_notifications':
            return {
                ...state, notifications: action.payload.messages
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
const fetchNotifications = dispatch => async () => {
    const notifications = await API.fetchNotifications();
    dispatch({type: 'fetch_notifications', payload: notifications})
};
export const {Provider, Context} = createDataContext(
    notificationsReducer,
    {fetchNotifications},
    {notifications: []}
)
```

**navigation/index.js here I call the 'action' fetchNotifications**

```
const MyTabs = (props) => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerRight: (props) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Notifications")}>
                            <Icon name="notifications"/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                )
            }}
        >           
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

```
const MyStack = () => {
const {fetchNotifications, state} = useContext(NotificationsContext);

    useEffect( () => {
        fetchNotifications();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Group>
                <Stack.Screen name="Tabs">
                    {(props) => <MyTabs {...props}  />}
                </Stack.Screen>
                <Stack.Screen name="Notifications">
                    {(props) => <NotificationsScreen {...props}/>}
                </Stack.Screen>
            </Stack.Group>
 </Stack.Navigator>
```

```
const Navigator = () => {
import { Provider as NotificationsProvider } from "...";
return (
    <NotificationsProvider>
       <NavigationContainer> <MyStack/> </NavigationContainer>
    </NotificationsProvider>
)
}
```

**Navigation.js --> here I want to use the state value from context but its never updated**

```
const Notifications = () => {
    const {state} = useContext(NotificationsContext);
    return <View>{state.notifications.map((notification, i) => <Text>{notification.title}</Text>)}</View>
    
}
```

```
export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
    const Context = createContext();
    const Provider = ({children}) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue)
        const boundActions = {};
        for (let key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
        }
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    };
    return { Context, Provider};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the problem is the following

> As RNN screens are not part of the same component tree, updating the values in the shared context does not trigger a re-render across all screens. However you can still use the React.Context per RNN screen component tree.

from react native navigation